# Do Kexec and Kdump work under VMware?

Tags: linux, debugging, vmware, kernel

Under Linux you can use [Kdump](http://lse.sourceforge.net/kdump/) to reliably capture the state of the system at the time of an OOPS ( kernel crash ) .  Does Kdump work the same when the kernel is running under VMWare?  I'm using VmWare Server 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if kdump will work.  Last time I tried kexec in VMware it would bomb and lock up the VM.  I guess there is a possibility kdump and/or kexec could work with the right settings but I didn't play with it much.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but VMware does provide the ability to connect gdb to a Linux guest from the host machine.  Or at least it did, it has been a long time since I tried it but it worked when I was debugging a kernel module.

I just looked in the VMware knowledge base and couldn't find any new information.  [This](http://stackframe.blogspot.com/2007/04/debugging-linux-kernels-with.html) is the old post I got my information from.  Also the [VMware forum](http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/general/guestdebugmonitor) for this type of debugging.  I haven't really been paying to attention to what the current status is.

Comment: +1: How long ago did you try this?  I was thinking about using VMWares ability to directly pass through USB traffic to the guest for developing a usb driver for a remote control I have.

Comment: Actually it had been more than a year.  I just tried an Ubuntu Karmic guest in Workstation 7 and kexec seems to work fine.  I don't know about kdump but I imagine it works also.  Kinda cool actually, wouldn't hurt to try it out, it's just a VM.

Comment: Cool.  I assume that if it works in Workstation 7 it would probably work in Server 2.0?  Did you use the method in your above answer to set it up?